Function to convert Google Sheet Table into one row
I have a problem with my google sheet. I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction.
I auto create a table with following structure:



A
B
C
D
E




Question
Answer a
Answer b
Answer c
Right Answer


ex Question
ex Answer
ex Answer
ex Answer
ex right Answer


ex Question
ex Answer
ex Answer
ex Answer
ex right Answer



etc
I want to format it in the following structure:



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H




Question 1
Answer 1a
Answer 1b
Answer 2b
Right Answer 1
Question 2
Answer 2a
so forth



Is there any function or way to make it happen in google sheets?
To make one table in one row
Thank you in advance!

It's difficult to tell based on the formatting in your question, but it sounds like your original data table looks like the table below and you want to be able to push it all to a single row.
You should be able to accomplish this using a single function:
=TOROW(A:E,1)




A
B
C
D
E




Question
Answer a
Answer b
Answer c
Right Answer


ex Question
ex Answer
ex Answer
ex Answer
ex right Answer


ex Question
ex Answer
ex Answer
ex Answer
ex right Answer




WOW that was simpler then i thought... THANK YOU very much!
